# How to render 180VR video though virtual camera?

Tags: rendering, camera, vr

I’d like to know if it’s possible to render a 180VR video from a virtual camera embedded inside my Blender animation.

The video can be edited in a second time with a ffmpeg command, for example with the hstack divider.

Comment: Could you define what specifically you mean by 180VR video? 360° panoramic video? What's VR about it? Set the camera lens to panoramic type in the camera properties, Properties Editor. It's not yet supported in EEVEE, so you'll need to use Cycles for rendering, but it is possible to adjust render settings for Cycles to be fast as well (lowering the quality of rendering). If you need some more interaction then looking around from it, you will need some other software.

Comment: I was referring to the standard of google, to allow semi spherical view (capturing what's front of the camera but not behind).

However I'm also interested to capture 360 degrees around the camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you need to render a left and right side simultanously, you are reffering to "Stereoscopy".

Blender stores stereoscopy in two places: Output Properties, and Camera Properties.

### Output Properties

[image]

First, you need to enable the Stereoscopy panel, it will add a "Views" subpanel in the Output panel.

From there, you can choose how the stereoscopy will be stored in your file. Individual will save a different file with L/R prefixes for each view. Stereo 3D will store both views in the same file, with different "storage" modes. In VR, we often use Top-Bottom or Side-By-Side.

### Camera Properties

[image]

You need to set your camera type to Panoramic, and use an Equirectangular panorama type.

You can adjust the Latitude and Longitude, but I guess the default ones are the "180VR" you refer to.

Last but not least, enable Spherical Stereo in Stereoscopy panel, this will change the way the panoramic effect is projected.

### Display warning

The only way to see the result is to same your image. Your viewport and the render result viewer will both show your render differently from what it will be in the final image file.

The render result and viewport's camera view in every shading mode except rendered will show it as cyan-magenta anaglyph stereoscopy. Viewport in rendered shading will alternate between each "eye" of the camera at frequent interval.

[image]

It is normal, it's just a preview. The accurate result is in the saved render file:

[image]